# Match from last occurrence using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text like this:

```
hello world /* select a from table_b
*/ some other text with new line cha
racter and there are some blocks of 
/* any string */ select this part on
ly 
////RESULT rest string
```

The text is multilined and I need to extract from last occurrence of "*/" until "////RESULT". In this case, the result should be:

```
 select this part on
ly
```

How to achieve this in perl?

I have attempted `\\\*/(.|\n)*////RESULT` but that will start from first "*/"

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I have attempted \\*/(.|\n)*////RESULT but that will starts from first "*/"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A useful trick in cases like this is to prefix the regexp with the greedy pattern `.*`, which will try to match as many characters as possible before the rest of the pattern matches.  So:

```
my ($match) = ($string =~ m!^.*\*/(.*?)////RESULT!s);
```

Let's break this pattern into its components:

- `^.*` starts at the beginning of the string and matches as many characters as it can.  (The `s` modifier allows `.` to match even newlines.)  The beginning-of-string anchor `^` is not strictly necessary, but it ensures that the regexp engine won't waste too much time backtracking if the match fails.
- `\*/` just matches the literal string `*/`.
- `(.*?)` matches and captures any number of characters; the `?` makes it ungreedy, so it prefers to match as few characters as possible in case there's more than one position where the rest of the regexp can match.
- Finally, `////RESULT` just matches itself.

Since the pattern contains a lot of slashes, and since I wanted to avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome), I decided to use alternative regexp delimiters.  Exclamation points (`!`) are a popular choice, since they don't collide with any normal regexp syntax.

---

**Edit:** Per discussion with ikegami below, I guess I should note that, if you want to use this regexp as a sub-pattern in a longer regexp, and if you want to guarantee that the string matched by `(.*?)` will *never* contain `////RESULT`, then you should wrap those parts of the regexp in an [independent `(?>)` subexpression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%3epattern)), like this:

```
my $regexp = qr!\*/(?>(.*?)////RESULT)!s;
...
my $match = ($string =~ /^.*$regexp$some_other_regexp/s);
```

The `(?>)` causes the pattern inside it to fail rather than accepting a suboptimal match (i.e. one that extends beyond the first substring matching `////RESULT`) even if that means that the rest of the regexp will fail to match.

Comment: I hate `.*?`. It doesn't guarantee not to match what you're hoping it doesn't match. In this particular pattern, it works quite well, except it doesn't match the lat `*/` if it appears after `////RESULT`. That's probably a good thing, though.

Comment: @ikegami: Actually, the behavior of `.*?` is perfectly well defined; see ["Combining RE pieces" in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Combining-RE-Pieces).

Comment: I never said it wasn't defined. I'm quite familiar with what it does, and what it's used for, and those two aren't the same thing. Show me a pattern with two `.*?`, and I'll show you a bug or a useless `?` (performance aside).

Comment: Gave a +1 for the explanation, even though I consider your answer unmaintanable.

Comment: Ah, so you just find `.*?` unintuitive? If "what you're hoping" it will do is "match anything except the pattern immediately after it", then no, it doesn't do that (although you _can_ get that effect by wrapping it and the pattern after it in `(?>)`). I'm not really disagreeing with you there, I just think the proper answer to that is not "don't use `.*?`" but "don't use `.*?` unless you understand what it does".

Comment: Unintuitive? I suppose "it's used to do one thing but actually does nothing" falls under the definition of unintuitive, but I find it loses something in the translation.

Answer (score 5):

```
(?:(?!STRING).)*
```

matches any number of characters that don't contain `STRING`. It's like `[^a]`, but for strings instead of characters.

You can take shortcuts if you know certain inputs won't be encountered (like Kenosis and Ilmari Karonen did), but this is what what matches what you specified:

```
my ($segment) = $string =~ m{
    \*/
    ( (?: (?! \*/ ). )* )
    ////RESULT
    (?: (?! \*/ ). )*
    \z
}xs;
```

If you don't care if `*/` appears after `////RESULT`, the following is the safest:

```
my ($segment) = $string =~ m{
    \*/
    ( (?: (?! \*/ ). )* )
    ////RESULT
}xs;
```

You didn't specify what should happen if there are two `////RESULT` that follow the last `*/`. The above matches until the last one. If you wanted to match until the first one, you'd use

```
my ($segment) = $string =~ m{
    \*/
    ( (?: (?! \*/ | ////RESULT ). )* )
    ////RESULT
}xs;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = <<'END';
hello world /* select a from table_b
*/ some other text with new line cha
racter and there are some blocks of 
/* any string */ select this part on
ly 
////RESULT
END

my ($segment) = $string =~ m!\*/([^/]+)////RESULT$!s;

print $segment;
```

Output:

```
 select this part on
ly
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain what is the ! after m and what is [^/] ?

Comment: That doesn't permit any `/` in between `*/` and `////RESULT`. (It's also isn't guaranteed to match the last `*/`, but that's probably not a problem.)

Comment: @PeitiPeterLi - Since there were forward slashes in the string, `m!!` was used for matching.  Note that [ikegami](http://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) used `m{}`.  The `[]` denotes a character set, and `[^/]` means not (`^`) a forward slash.

Comment: @ikegami - Yes--excellent point about the regex excluding any / in the capture.  I've oversimplified this issue.  Always appreciate your comments.  Thank you.